# Javascript weird loop with body onload

Tags: javascript

I have this file on my server: (Index.html)

`<script src="script.js"></script>`

Then Script.js:

```
function generateUUID() {
    var d = new Date().getTime();
    var uuid = 'xxx-xxx-4xx-yxxx-xxxxyyyyxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
        var r = (d + Math.random()*16)%16 | 0;
        d = Math.floor(d/16);
        return (c=='x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8)).toString(16);
    });
    return uuid;
};
window.onload=doit;


function doit() {
    var uuidme;
    uuidme = generateUUID();
    window.location.href = "/test?uuid=" + uuidme; 
}
```

And the get varible goes crazy, it never stops changing the code which is NOT even close to what I would like.

Comment: Well, assigning to `window.location.href` will load that page. And if that's the same page the code is in, then it will constantly refresh. Is that not what you want? What do you want then?

Comment: If the script is loaded at /test, then it runs every time it loads, even when loaded with a query string.

Comment: @LeFex Is there any way around this?

Comment: I don't see the point with doing this thing in the first place. If you absolutely need this functionality, you'll have to either check the query string for an id, and not run the code if there is one, or maybe save it in a cookie, and use that as a condition.

Answer (score 0):

before redirecting, check the url to see if you're already at the right spot with a uuid set. You can do this by scanning the url for the variable `uuid` using indexOf `window.location.href.indexOf('uuid=') == -1`:

```
function generateUUID() {
    var d = new Date().getTime();
    var uuid = 'xxx-xxx-4xx-yxxx-xxxxyyyyxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
        var r = (d + Math.random()*16)%16 | 0;
        d = Math.floor(d/16);
        return (c=='x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8)).toString(16);
    });
    return uuid;
};
window.onload=doit;


function doit() {
    // make sure we dont find uuid set in the url already
    if(window.location.href.indexOf('uuid=') == -1) {
        var uuidme;
        uuidme = generateUUID();
        window.location.href = "/test?uuid=" + uuidme; 
    }
}
```